# Display a badge icon on the app menu without number

Tags: android

Is it possible to display a badge icon without a number on the app menu ?

This lib [Leolin shortcut badger](https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger) permits to display a badge with an icon but does not permit to display the badge only. The feature is not present on Android but permitted by the launcher used.

The default code used to display the badge is :

```
private static final String INTENT_ACTION = "android.intent.action.BADGE_COUNT_UPDATE";
private static final String INTENT_EXTRA_BADGE_COUNT = "badge_count";
private static final String INTENT_EXTRA_PACKAGENAME = "badge_count_package_name";
private static final String INTENT_EXTRA_ACTIVITY_NAME = "badge_count_class_name";
Intent intent = new Intent(INTENT_ACTION);
    intent.putExtra(INTENT_EXTRA_BADGE_COUNT, badgeCount);
    intent.putExtra(INTENT_EXTRA_PACKAGENAME, getContextPackageName());
    intent.putExtra(INTENT_EXTRA_ACTIVITY_NAME, getEntryActivityName());
    mContext.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Using this code with badgecount to 0 or null or without the extra INTENT_EXTRA_BADGE_COUNT does not display the badge.

Are there any extra parameters that permit this?

Comment: If you mean in the launcher then the best place to look is in the custom launcher code you use.

Comment: I mean the application launcher installed on the device (constructor dependent).